# pandas df.plot.scatter fails but df.plot produces plot

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe, plot

I want to produce scatter plots of data from a pandas df, sample below. 
[image]
I can produce line plots with:

```
ax = df_stats.plot(x = 't', y = 't_TI_var_ws')
ax1 = ax.twinx()
df_stats.plot(x='t',y='t_TI_var_pwr',ax=ax1, color='g')
```

[image]

but when I try to use `.scatter` to plot the same data as a scatter plot I get the error `KeyError: 't'`

```
ax = df_stats.plot.scatter(x = 't', y = 't_TI_var_ws')
ax1 = ax.twinx()
df_stats.plot.scatter(x='t',y='t_TI_var_pwr',ax=ax1, color='g')
```

Comment: what happens if you do: `df_stats.plot(x='t',y='t_TI_var_pwr',ax=ax1, color='g', kind='scatter')`

Comment: the same error `KeyError: 't'`

Comment: please provide sample data

Comment: @YOLO `type('t')` returns `'str'`, `t` is listed as `datetime` in the variable explorer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your column to is a timestamp. To use scatter it must be a float.
You can plot scatter plot with:

```
ax = df_stats.plot(x = 't', y='t_TI_var_pwr',style='o')
```